# MAJA cloud mask TIFF file comparison with shapefile

Tags: r, cloudmasking

I have created could mask using MAJA the result is TIFF file.
I have a reference mask file which is a shapefile.

I would like to see how accurately MAJA can produce the cloud mask as much as possible. So I want to create a confusion matrix that compare the pixels or points(not sure) MAJA vs Reference. Then I want to calculate the user producer accuracy and F1 score.

How can I compare them using the confusion matrix in R??

Left is the cloud mask from MAJA software right is the reference shapefile and they are in the same coordinate system and same extent

MAJA has values between 0-7 and reference has only 1.

[image: left is the cloud mask from MAJA software right is the reference shapefile]

Comment: Could you edit your Q with some more details? Maybe show maps of the two things, show us if they are in the same coordinate system or same extent? Is the shp file polygons? What attributes do the polygons have? Could you even let us have the data to work with, or similar data? The answer is possibly to convert the tif raster to points and then sample the shapefile.

Comment: I have edited the question Hope it is more clear now. @Spacedman

Comment: Do those two objects overlap when plotted together? Are the coordinate systems the same? How are you wanting to compare the 0-1 values in the polygon with values from 0 to 7 in the raster? Are you expecting to create a 2x8 confusion matrix? But there's no values for 2 to 7 in the polygon...

Comment: yes, they are overlapped. These values represent bits. for ins; 7 = 2**2 + 2**1 + 2**1, I use <https://labo.obs-mip.fr/multitemp/sentinel-2/majas-native-sentinel-2-format/#English> this for interpretation. I guess inside the polygon is cloud = 0 outside the polygon is clear = 1. I am not sure exactly they want me to compare these 2. @Spacedman